# Capturing active application notifications in macOS/React Native

Tags: swift, react-native, macos, notifications

I'm building a macOS application using React Native. I want to find out when the user switches applications and grab screenshots when they occur. I have the following toy implementation:

```swift
import Foundation
import AppKit

@objc(ScreenShotModule)
public class ScreenShotModule: NSObject, RCTBridgeModule {
  
  public static func moduleName() -> String! {
    return "ScreenShotModule"
  }
  
  var count:Int = 0
  
  override init() {
    super.init()
    print("called init")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(appDidBecomeActive),
      name: NSWorkspace.didActivateApplicationNotification,
      object: nil)
  }
  
  @objc func appDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("got notified")
    let displayId = CGMainDisplayID()
    guard let image = CGDisplayCreateImage(displayId) else { return }
        
    let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: image)
    guard let imageData = bitmapRep.representation(using: .png, properties: [:]) else { return }
        
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let directoryURLs = fileManager.urls(for: .picturesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        
    if let documentDirectory = directoryURLs.first {
      let filePath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("screenshot_\(count).png")
      do {
        try imageData.write(to: filePath)
        count += 1
        print("Screenshot saved to: \(filePath)")
      } catch {
        print("Error saving screenshot: \(error)")
      }
    }
  }
  
  @objc func triggerAppDidBecomeActive() {
      let dummyNotification = NSNotification(name: NSNotification.Name(""), object: nil)
      self.appDidBecomeActive(notification: dummyNotification)
  }
  
  @objc func postNotification() {
    print("posted!")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSWorkspace.didActivateApplicationNotification, object: "foo",
                                    userInfo: ["key": "Value"])
  }
  
  @objc public static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

This works in that I can manually take screenshots via `triggerAppDidBecomeActive`, and I can take screenshots upon posting fake events via `postNotification`. However, while I'm running the app and switching between applications, no screenshots are taken. So somehow, my switching applications does not send events to, or otherwise does not trigger:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(appDidBecomeActive),
      name: NSWorkspace.didActivateApplicationNotification,
      object: nil)
```

I've turned on and off application sandboxing without change. I've also tried using `DistributedNotificationCenter` and that doesn't work either. How can I figure out when a user switches active applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver`, but you should be using `NSWorkspace.shared.addObserver`

I believe this is universally true for the `NSWorkspace.*` notifications.